# Why differentiate between continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Before starting I want to say that my main language is not english so you may find some grammar mistakes. I will try to avoid making them as much as I can, so please forgive me.

A few months ago I decided that I wanted to learn Calculus so I got some books and started to study, during that time I faced a statement that is pretty common among math definitions related to it, and that statement is:

> $f(x)$ is continuous at $[a,b]$ and differentiable at $(a,b)$

What I was thinking was that a limit needs a closed interval to compute its value, but after making some research I found that the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $0$, so I started to make myself this question.

If we consider, for example $f(x) = x^2$. and the interval $[1,3]$. We know that the function is differentiable and continuous at its whole domain but we do we say that it has to be continuous at $[1,3]$ and differentiable at $(1,3)$, this of course, considering the function over the interval mentioned before, when in fact it is differentiable at $1$ and $3$.

Also the function $\sqrt{x}$ is considered continuous at its whole domain, even also at $x = 0$ but it is not differentiable at 0. Why?

Why do we do this difference between $[a,b]$ and $(a,b)?$

Sorry if I did not express myself the best way possible, again, English is not my main language.

Comment: Differentiable on $(1,3)$ does not mean differentiable only on $(1,3)$. The funciton may be differentiable on $[1,3]$ or even the whole real line.

Comment: Definitions are your friends in studying mathematics.  You ask why the square root function $\sqrt x$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.  The first point to make is that the definition of having a derivative is not satisfied there.  You can tackle that issue yourself with the tools of first year calculus.

Comment: This is a typical hypothesis of many standard theorems. Usually one tries to formulate minimal hypotheses which are easy to verify. So in current case most of those theorems don't need the differentiability at end points. Contrast this with Darboux theorem (intermediate value theorem for derivatives) which needs derivatives on entire closed interval.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, now I understand

Answer (score 9):

Consider the following function. It's continuous on $[0,1]$, differentiable on $(0,1)$ but neither at $0$ nor $1$. Yet Rolle's theorem still applies and guarantees there is an $x$ in $(0,1)$ such that $f'(x)=0$. It's for this kind of situation that it's fundamental to distinguish between continuity on $[a,b]$ and differentiability on $(a,b)$. Had Rolle's theorem been proved for $f$ differentiable on $[a,b]$, we could not draw any conclusion for this function.

[image]

A bit of nostalgia: in the equivalent of first year undergraduate studies, in 1998, our teacher asked the class to try and prove Rolle's theorem. He inadvertently assumed differentiability on $[a,b]$, and I inadvertently drew the picture above to find inspiration. Until he noticed my mistake, which led him to notice his - that differentiability at the bounds is unnecessary. It's during those years I learned the importance of the slightest details in assumptions. I hope you will see too how important this is.

Comment: Eventually, would I be able to ask for a function to be continuous at [a,b] and ALSO differentiable at [a,b]? There is any restriction? by the way, thanks to everybody for your answers, you are helping me a lot.

Comment: @Lev1 Of course you can, and you can still (for instance) apply Rolle's theorem, but you have more than is required for Rolle's theorem. The advantage of loosening as much as possible the assumptions of a theorem is that you can apply it to a wider class of problems. As the assumptions are satisfied, it usually doesn't matter if you have more than is required (it could be a sign that you may apply a stronger theorem, but not always).

Comment: @Lev1 And even if it's not about Rolle's theorem, it's not a problem to have a function differentiable at the bounds of an interval, in case it disturbs you. You'll take the left and right limits for those derivatives. And function need not be differentiable, nor continuous (but if it's differentiable at $x_0$, it's also continuous at $x_0$). It may also be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable nowhere, or only at some points, etc. The mathematical zoo if full of that kind of pathologic counterexamples, useful in topology.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answers. It seems a lot.
I guess that the whole problem started when I discovered that lim x-> 0 sqrt(x) was equal to 0, so I started to wonder why math definitions usually make that distinction. But If I understood, correctly, it is because it is not needed to have the function differentiable at f(a) and f(b).

Comment: @Lev1 I see. Then keep in mind that differentiable at $x_0$ $\implies$ continuous at $x_0$, but the converse is not true.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: we often desire for the assumptions of a theorem to be least restrictive possible, so that the theorem is most general and widely applicable. It turns out that in many theorems you require continuity on $[a, b]$, but you do not actually need differentiability at the endpoints, only on $(a, b)$.

For example, in the proof of [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), we have a function $f$ defined on $[a, b]$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ and we wish to establish the existence of a point $c \in (a, b)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$. We know that $f$ must have the maximum on $[a, b]$ and we define $d$ to be an argument for which the maximum is attained. Now there are two cases. Either $d$ is an endpoint of $[a, b]$ or an interior point. In the first case $f$ is the constant function and we are done without explicitly invoking differentiability of $f$ (even though every constant function on a suitable domain is differentiable). In the second case we invoke differentiability in order to say that $f'(d)$ exists before we observe that $f'(d)=0$.

This example shows that sometimes differentiability of a function in the interior $(a, b)$ of an interval $[a, b]$ may simply be all that is needed to establish a conclusion.

There is also the subtle point that consideration of differentiability and derivative of a function defined on a closed interval at an endpoint of the interval requires that we appropriately interpret the definition as referring to one-sided limit. The subtlety disappears if we only consider differentiability and derivatives on open sets.

---

Regarding the reason that the function $\sqrt{x}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ it is because the tangent to its plot becomes vertical at this point. Equivalently, the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0_+}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0_+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} $$ does not exist.

Comment: I loved this answer. From what I understood, when we have some theorem that only requires assumption of differentiability on $(a,b)$, (like Rolle's Theorem), it usually means that when we analyse the case at the end points, the theorem devolves into a very special case (eg. maximum at either endpoint implies that the function is constant), after which differentiability in the hypothesis wouldn't even matter, either because it's not relevant, or, in the case of Rolle's Theorem, you get differentiability on $[a,b]$ for free in the special case.

Comment: I wanted to ask another perhaps unrelated question: When people formulate theorems on real-functions, they normally start "Let $f:\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$." I now understand the reason for distinguishing between the open and closed intervals here due to your answer, but I wonder, would it be more useful to extend the hypothesis? It seems like a natural generalisation is to assume continuity on some compact set $K$, and differentiability on some open subset $G \subseteq K$. Why not ditch the intervals enitrely?

Comment: Thank you! I think the reason people stick to intervals is that they actually achieve the same generality while being more concrete. After all, the standard topology on the real line is generated by the open intervals.

Answer (score 2):

The classic counterexample to differentiability is $f(x) = \vert x \vert$ and its translates.

Consider e.g. $g(x) = \vert x\vert -2$. You can apply the Intermediate Value Theorem, Rolle's Theorem, Mean Value Theorem, etc. to $g$ (and indeed $f$, although that may be less interesting) on the interval from $0$ to $k$, for any positive integer $k$, despite the lack of differentiability at $(0,-2)$.

It's worth considering whether you can drop the continuity assumption at the endpoint. You cannot. Hint: Try a removable singularity, such as a step function.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you have a function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, the differentiability of $f$ at the left endpoint is defined as
$$
f'(a):=\lim_{h\color{blue}{\downarrow} 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}
$$
whenever the limit exists. If the limit does not exist, then $f$ is not differentiable at $x=a$.

For your example $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, you can check that the following limit does not exist:
$$
\lim_{h\color{blue}{\downarrow} 0}\frac{\sqrt{h}}{h}
$$

Differentiability at a point is a local property of a function. Usually, what matters most is the interior points of the domain when talking about derivatives; note that every point in $(a,b)$ is an interior point.